# Use magrittr to pipe download.file() to another function

Tags: r, magrittr

How can I use `magrittr` to pipe the output of `download.file()` directly to `readxl()` without first saving to a temporary location?

For example, I have the following code:

```
download.file(www, method="curl") %>%
  read_excel(x, sheet ="List 1", range="A3:L1902") -> cw
```

This gives me an error because I am missing the `destfile=` argument... any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want to save the file, you could open and pipe a connection.  See `?connections`

Comment: download.file returns an integer, so you can't pipe it to read_excel

Answer (score 1):

I tried the idea of `connections` but from my searches `readxl`doesn't support reading from urls (you can look [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/371) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/278)). However, I found [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/183) something that might help you.

The `rio` package have a wrapper around `read_excel` which allow the use of urls.
You can even add the argument `sheet` to chose which sheet to load. In addition, from my experience, if you know the file extension you'll use - add the `format`  argument.

```
install.packages("rio") # if needed

df <- rio::import("https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/SDTM/SDTM%20Terminology.xls", 
                      format = "xls", sheet = "SDTM Terminology 2018-03-30")
```